# How to add fixed point with two's complement fixed point?

Tags: math, twos-complement, fixed-point

I want to multiply unsigned integer 5432 by 0.01 and then add/subtract 0.3. Instead of using floats I want to use fixed-point arithmetic. Here are my steps:

1) ((1 << 16) * 0.01) = 655 => Fixed point Q0.16

2) 655 * 5432 = 3557960 => Fixed point Q16.16

3) ((1 << 16) * 0.3) = 19660 => Fixed point Q0.16

4) Add 0.3: 3557960 + 19660 = 3577620 => Convert to float = 54.59 which is pretty much same as using floating calculations: 5432 * 0.01 + 0.3 = 54.62

5) Subtract 0.3: find two's complement of 19660 => 45876, now 3577620 + 45876 = 3623496 => 55.29 which is not as expected 5432 * 0.01 - 0.3 = 54.02

Can anyone verify that I am correct in point 1-4, and what I'm missing in point 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is that you assume that 2-complement representation is independent of the word size. It is not. 16-bit to 2-complement for `19660` is `2^16 - 19660` or `45876` but since you are working with 32-bit number you need a corresponding 2-complement which is `2^32 - 19960` or `4294947636`. In other words when you extend 2-complement from 16-bits to 32-bits you should fill top bytes with the sign bit i.e. `1` for negative values. You can see that in binary both values are actually the same under such extension:

```
45876      =                   10110011_00110100 (16-bit binary)
4294947636 = 11111111_11111111_10110011_00110100 (32-bit binary)
```

If you add `3557960 + 4294947636` you'll get `4298505596` or if you truncate it back to a 32-bit value - `3538300` which is a fixed point representation of `53,99`

Comment: Great! That makes sense.